# Perfect circles in the Mandelbrot set?

Tags: reference-request, fractals, complex-dynamics

It is known that the boundary of the period 2 hyperbolic component of the Mandelbrot set is a perfect circle of radius $\frac{1}{4}$ centered at $-1$.  Moreover it is known that the boundaries of the circle-like period 3 hyperbolic components are not perfect circles (["A Parameterization of the Period 3 Hyperbolic Components of the Mandelbrot Set",  Dante Giarrusso, Yuval Fisher](http://www.ams.org/proc/1995-123-12/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3.pdf)).

Question: is the period 2 component the *only* hyperbolic component in the Mandelbrot set whose boundary is a perfect circle?

Similarly, is the period 1 component the *only* hyperbolic component in the Mandelbrot set whose boundary is a perfect cardioid?

I suspect the answer to both questions is "yes", but haven't found any conclusive references.

Comment: For the first question, it appears that there is a sequence of circular components converging to the so-called [Myreberg point](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/julia/altplane.html). I don't recall seeing a proof that they are circular, though, anywhere.

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis An easy numerical experiment shows that the disk-*like* component of period 4 centered at $c\approx1.32$ just to the left of the period two bulb is *not* a perfect circle. I'm confident that Claude is correct in his conjecture but I don't have a definitive argument either. :)

Comment: @MarkMclure: I hear you. Can you please elaborate on the numerical experiment which shows that the period 4 bulb is not a circle?

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis http://lpaste.net/7577354575468822528 is my program performing the numerical experiment, output at http://i.imgur.com/J7uFX5y.png

Comment: @Claude: Ok. Looks like the output is showing the deviation for 3 separate components or am I missing something?

Comment: @YiannisGalidakis almost, it shows deviation for 12 components starting with the period 2 (flat black line at top) heading left along the period-doubling cascade - I think period 4 is red and period 8 bright green, the remaining higher-period components seem to converge to the other visible curve (actually many curves atop each other at the resolution of the plot)

Comment: @Claude: Got it. You changed the resolution and I now see all the lines. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe is it possible to show that degree of equation defining boundary is greater then 1 so it cannot be a circle.

Comment: http://linas.org/art-gallery/bud/bud.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something I tried, thanks to Adam's comment for the basic idea for $p \ge 3$.  This answer is missing some details, comments suggesting improvements are welcome, as would be other answers that fill in the gaps.  It also relies on the fact (?) that:

$$\forall 0 \neq a \in \mathbb{C}, 0 \neq b \in \mathbb{C}, 1 < m \in \mathbb{N} . \exists x . |a e^{i x} + b e^{i m x}| \neq 1$$

---

Let $F(z, c) = z^2 + c$ with $F^{p+1}(z, c) = F^p(F(z, c), c)$.  Now the boundary of a hyperbolic component can be parameterized by $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ by the solution of the equation system:
$$
F^p(z,c) = z \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}F^p(z,c) = e^{i \theta}
$$
Now the question reduces to showing $c$ is of the form $c = c_0 + r_0 e^{i \phi}$ where $c_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $r_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants and $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$.

$F^p(z,c) = z$ defines a polynomial of even degree $P(z) = 0$, whose constant coefficient is the product of its roots and is a polynomial in $c$ of degree $2^{p-1}$.  The roots include those of $F^q(z, c) = z$ where $q | p$.  Also, $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}F^p(z, c) = 2^p \Pi z_k$ where the $z_k$ are the $p$ roots in the periodic orbit of the desired solution $z$ (all $z_k$ are roots of $F^p(z, c) = z$, the remaining roots have lower period).

Case $p = 1$:
$$ z^2 + c_0 + r_0 e^{i \phi} = z \\
\therefore z = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4(c_0 + r_0 e^{i \phi})}}{2} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = 2 z = e^{i \theta}
$$

Now $|e^{i \theta}| = 1$ but $\exists x . |2 z| = |1 \pm \sqrt{x}| \neq 1$, so conclude that period $1$ component is not a perfect circle.

Case $p = 2$:

The equations reduce to
$$ 4(1 + c_0 + r_0 e^{i \phi}) = e^{i \theta} $$
with obvious solution $c_0 = -1, r_0 = \frac{1}{4}, \phi = \theta$, so conclude that the period 2 component is a perfect circle.

Case $p = 3$:

The equations reduce to
$$ 8 (c^3 + 2c^2 + c + 1) = e^{i \theta} \text{ where } c = c_0 + r_0 e^{i \phi}$$
For this to hold, the coefficients of $e^{i k \phi}$ must be zero for all $k > 1$.  But setting $k = 3$ implies $r_0^3 = 0$ but we know that $r_0 > 0$ as hyperbolic components have non-empty interior.  Contradiction, conclude that no period 3 component is a perfect circle.

Case $p > 3$:

Similarly to the $p = 3$ case, get a polynomial of degree $m > 1$ in $e^{i \phi}$ whose highest term has coefficient $r_0^m$.  It remains to show that the polynomial really does have degree greater than $1$.  The constant coefficient (product of roots) is a polynomial of degree $2^{p-1}$ in $c$, divided by the corresponding constant coefficient of all smaller divisors of the period gives:

$$m = 2^{p-1} - \sum_{q | p, q < p} 2^{q-1}$$

which solved numerically gives:

$$\begin{aligned}
p & & & m \\
1 & & & 1 \\
2 & & & 1 \\
3 & & & 3 \\
4 & & & 5 \\
5 & & & 15 \\
6 & & & 25 \\
\vdots
\end{aligned}$$

Finally, $m > 1$ for all $p \ge 3$ because $\exists q > 1 . q \nmid p$.