# Difference between limbs and bulbs in Mandelbrot Set

Tags: complex-dynamics

Taking a look to the picture of the Mandelbrot set, one immediately notice its biggest component which we call the *main cardioid*. This region is composed by the parameters $c$ for which $p_c$ is hyperbolic when its periodic point is a *fixed point* (that is whose period is $n=1$). It turns out that these parameters are all of the form
$$
c_{\mu}:=\frac {\mu}2\left(1-\frac {\mu}2\right)
$$
when $\mu$ runs in the open unitary disk $\Delta_1$.

For every rational number $\frac pq$ ($p,q$ coprime), there is a circular shaped "bulb" tangent to the main cardioid at the point $c_{\mu}$ for $\mu=e^{2\pi i\frac pq}$, called the *$\frac pq$-bulb* (clearly $0\le\frac pq\le1$), consisting of all parameters $c$ whose polynomial $p_c$ admits $q$-periodic points.

The best current estimate known was proved by Yoccoz in the Hubbard paper *Local connectivity of Julia sets and bifurcation loci: three theorems of J.C.Yoccoz*, which states that the diameters of the $\frac pq$-limbs tends to zero like $1/q$. Nonetheless numerical experiments suggest the following
conjeture:

> The diameter of the limbs tends to zero like $1/{q^2}$.

Or maybe one can consider a broader problem:

> Is the Yoccoz asymptotics $1/q$ sharp, or can it be improved?

Some questions for you:

-It is clear that we have different bulbs with the same denominator $q$; are they all the different circles tangents to the main cardioid, which have the same radius depending on $q$?

-In Wikipedia it seems that the same object is first called *bulb*, then called *limb*: are these only different names for the same object?

-it seems that these bulbs are exact circles; is this true for all of them?

I ask this because studying the decay rate of the diameter of the $\frac pq$-limbs, if we fix $q$ and we call $p_1,\dots,p_n$ all the integers coprime with $q$ (and $\le q$), it would be nice if all the $\frac{p_1}q,\dots,\frac{p_n}q$-limbs have *exactly* the same diameter. Then the question of ratio decay would be *sharper defined* (and I'm not sure if it is actually necessarily for the question to be *well defined*).

**EDIT** We can put concepts in order as follows:

There is a unique region $\Omega_0$ composed by the parameters $c$ for which $p_c$ is hyperbolic when its periodic point is a *fixed point* (that is whose period is $n=1$). It turns out that $\Omega_0$ is bounded by the main cardioid and the parameters composing $\Omega_0$ are all of the form
$$
c_{\mu}:=\frac {\mu}2\left(1-\frac {\mu}2\right)
$$
when $\mu$ runs in the open unitary disk $\Delta_1$.
For every rational number $\frac pq$ (such that $0<\frac pq<1$ and $p,q$ coprime), we define the *$\frac pq$-limb* $M_{\frac pq}$ as the connected component of $M\setminus\overline{\Omega_0}$ tangent to the main cardioid at the point $c_{\mu}$ for $\mu=e^{2\pi i\frac pq}$; the biggest circular shaped "bulb" in $M_{\frac pq}$, called the *$\frac pq$-bulb* and denoted as $\Omega_{\frac pq}$, consists of all parameters $c$ whose polynomial $p_c$ admits $q$-periodic points.

We note that even though the boundary of the bulb $M_{\frac12}$
%period $2$ hyperbolic component of the Mandelbrot set
is a perfect circle of radius $\frac14$ centered at $-1$, not all the bulbs are circles; see the case of the bulbs of period $3$.

Do you see contradiction/errors/wrong definitions?

Comment: There is an exact parametrization of the period-3 components presented in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/proc/1995-123-12/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3/S0002-9939-1995-1301497-3.pdf) and they are *not* perfect circles. I doubt that the $p/q$ bulbs for $q>4$ are equal sizes. If correct, that shouldn't be too hard to check.

Comment: Note that a related question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1857237/).

Comment: Thanks. The related question, answers only partially to mine problems. Then main point is to have a precise definition of limbs and bulbs, to get the difference between them.

Comment: https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/hubbard.pdf is the paper mentioned, the asymptotics are Remark 4.3 therein. I'm not sure if the p/q limb of a primitive satellite component (aka baby Mandelbrot set cardioid) includes the decorations that extend beyond the filaments of the baby Mandelbrot set; what are the numerical experiments you refer to?

Comment: "the $\frac{p}{q}$-bulb ... consists of all parameters $c$ whose polynomial $P_c$ admits $q$-periodic points." could be clarified by explicitly stating $c \in M_\frac{p}{q}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p/q-limb is a part of Mandelbrot set contained inside p/q-wake.

Strict definition is in paper : [Periodic Orbits, Externals Rays and the Mandelbrot Set: An Expository Account](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905169) by John W. Milnor

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/def_cqp

Answer (score 2):

The size estimate that I use (though I forget where I found it, references would be appreciated) for bulbs bifurcating from cardioid-like shapes at rational internal angle $p/q$ (in lowest terms, measured in turns) is:

$$ R_{p/q} = R_1 \sin\left(\pi\frac{p}{q}\right) \frac{1}{q^2}$$

For secondary bulbs bifurcating from circle-like shapes, omit the $\sin$ factor.

I think (though I'm not sure) the term "limb" might refer either to everything in the wake of the two external rays landing at the root of the bulb:
[image: a diagram of the Mandelbrot set with some features labelled] eg $1/3$ limb is between $.(001)$ and $.(010)$ rays expressed in binary

Or that wake minus the wake of its principal hub (the largest $3$-way spiral above the antenna from the bulb's $1/2 \to 1/2 \to \ldots$ bifurcation sequence)

And I think the "diameter" of a limb might not be in Cartesian space, but in terms of the external angles.  For example, the "width of a wake" is the difference between the two angles (eg the $1/3$ bulb's wake has width $1/7$).

Comment: Thank you Claude! Very useful. I've edited my answer with the notion taken so far. Anyway: where did you found the notions about diameter? Thanks again

Comment: @Joe https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9411238 "Internal addresses in the Mandelbrot set and Galois groups of polynomials" by Dierk Schleicher

Comment: @Joe I found the paper, I think I was wrong about diameter (I now think it is in Cartesian space).

Answer (score 1):

"it seems that these bulbs are exact circles; is this true for all of them?"

Shape of hyperbolic components of Mandelbrot set:

- Period 1 component is a cardioid
- period 2 component is a circle
- all other components look like circle or cardioid but they are higher degree curves ( [solution of boundary equations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/Mandelbrot_set/boundary#solving_boundary_equations) )